# Deploying serverless.yml just like cloud formation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I am new to serverless world. So just wondering is it possible to deploy the serverless.yml just like we deploy any other  cloudformation template using AWS console etc or it is only possible through serverless CLI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a direct answer, but for using regular `CloudFormation` tools, ideally one would like to get the transformed, **raw CloudFormation template** which is an outcome of serverless transformations of the SAM template.

For now, there is no build in dedicated functionality for that in SAM toolset. However, there has been a **GitHub issue** already made for such a feature:

- [cli command to transform sam template to regular cloudformation template?](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/issues/1141)

The issue also indicates that `sam validate --debug` is a workaround on getting the raw template, not ideal though. Thus having this template with some **manual fixes**, a regular CloudFormation deployment can be attempted.